# Back transform mixed-effects model's regression coefficients for fixed-effects from log to original scale

Tags: r, regression, transformation, lme4, coefficients

I am running a mixed-effects model with the `lme4` package. The model specifications are: `log(dv) ~ 1 + A*B*C + (1+A*B|random1) + (1+A|random2)`, where `A` and `B` are within-group conditions and `C` is a between-group condition.

The first problem is that the coefficients for fixed effects are on the log scale and only the intercept makes sense when I do `exp(coef)` (see below).

The second problem is even if I do an exponentiation transform, how should I account for the random-effects structure? As I understand it, the random-effects structure affects the fixed-effects coefficients (I might be wrong here).

This is a sample output of my fixed-effects coefficients:

```
            Estimate
(Intercept) 6.533079
A1          0.062171
A2          0.077409
B1         -0.184366
B2         -0.154115
C           0.152238
A1:B1      -0.015494
A2:B1      -0.017655
A1:B2       0.001674
A2:B2      -0.003641
A1:C        0.013021
A2:C        0.038995
B1:C        0.010087
B2:C        0.013721
A1:B1:C     0.016025
A2:B1:C     0.016453
A1:B2:C     0.012746
A2:B2:C     0.003113
```

Now, `exp(6.533079)` gives 687.5118, which makes sense in the original scale, but the rest of the numbers do not make sense once transformed.

Comment: (1) this is more appropriate for [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) than StackOverflow, since it's about the interpretation & use of model parameters rather than the coding/programming itself; (2) in order to fully answer your question, we need to know a little bit more about how you intend to make use of the back-transformed information.  Do you want to state effect sizes? Make predictions ... ?

Comment: Should I repost it at CrossValidate? I just need the effect sizes, not predictions. I want to see the values the way they would appear if log transformed was not applied.

Comment: (1) It will get migrated automatically if enough high-rep users agree, but you might as well go ahead and do it yourself now.  (2) I understand your first sentence (just effect sizes) but not your second, or not how your second sentence fits with the first.  When you fit log-transformed data, the effects on the original scale are *multiplicative*, not additive ...

Comment: 1) The question now appears on CrossValidate --> https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/302448/back-transform-mixed-effects-models-regression-coefficients-for-fixed-effects-f 2) I think this shows my ignorance as to exactly how the estimates are computed. This is why I don't understand how I can back-transform.